# How to give Optional validation in formArray of formgroup in angular?

Tags: angular

**Component.ts**:(Here I have two formArray in formGroup. I need to make optional validation for both formArray. 
For Example, If i select agent_id in AgentArray, manufacturer_id in manArray is optional, same like if i select manufacturer_id in manArray,agent_id in AgentArray is optional. Could you please help me to do this??)

```
   manArray: FormArray;
  agentArray: FormArray;
 ngOnInit() {

    this.MaterialForm = new FormGroup({
      'myCode': new FormControl(null),
      'title': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'AgentArray': new FormArray([]),
       'ManufacturerArray': new FormArray([]),
      'remarks': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
})
   this.manArray = this.MaterialForm.get('ManufacturerArray') as FormArray;
    this.agentArray = this.MaterialForm.get("AgentArray") as FormArray;
}
 createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      iss: new FormControl(null),
      iss_expiry_date: new FormControl(null),
      manufacturer_id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)//I need to make this validation optional.. based on agent_id selection in createAgentItem function.. same like manufacturer also means vice-versa..
    });
  }

  createAgentItem(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      iss: new FormControl(null),
      iss_expiry_date: new FormControl(null),
      agent_id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }
addItem(){
 this.manArray.push(this.createItem());
    this.manufacturerUploader[this.manArray.length - 1] = new FileUploader({
      isHTML5: true,
    });
}
addAgentItem(){
 this.agentArray.push(this.createAgentItem());
    this.agentUploader[this.agentArray.length - 1] = new FileUploader({
      isHTML5: true,
    });
}
```

html:(Here I have Two formArray in formGroup.. I need to make optional validation for both formArray... For Example If i select agent_id in AgentArray, manufacturer_id in manArray is optional, same like if i select manufacturer_id in manArray,agent_id in AgentArray is optional.. Could you please help me to do this??)

```
  <div formArrayName="AgentArray" *ngFor="let formItem of agentArray.controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="boxClass">

                        <mat-form-field>
                            <!-- <input matInput formControlName="agent_id" placeholder="Agent Name"> -->
                            <mat-label>Select Agent</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="agent_id" required>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let agent of listOfAgents" [value]="agent.id"  
                    [disabled]="agent.disabled!=undefined || agent.disabled!=null">
                                    {{agent.company_name}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
          </div>
         <div formArrayName="ManufacturerArray" *ngFor="let item of manArray.controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="boxClass">

                        <mat-form-field>

                            <mat-label>Select Manufacturer</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="agent_id" required>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let manufacturer of listOfManufacturer" 
                    [disabled]="manufacturer.disabled!=undefined || manufacturer.disabled!=null" 
                              [value]="manufacturer.id">
                                    {{manufacturer.company_name}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first condition we could check the values of agent and manufacuter if its null give an alert else save the form.. this is the solution for my question.

```
save(){ if((<FormArray>this.MaterialForm.get('AgentArray')).at(this.indexSelected).value.agent_id == null && 
    (<FormArray>this.MaterialForm.get('ManufacturerArray')).at(this.indexSelected).value.agent_id == null){
           alert("Form should have either agent or manufacturer")
    }
    else{
// save the form
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add  validation and remove validation dynamically in formGroup with the help of `setValidators()`. 

In the Below code, whenever you select the agent at that time `validation.required` is added to agentArray and `validation.required` removed from the manufacturerArray and vice versa .

**html code**

```
<div formArrayName="AgentArray" *ngFor="let formItem of agentArray.controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="boxClass">

        <mat-form-field>
            <!-- <input matInput formControlName="agent_id" placeholder="Agent Name"> -->
            <mat-label>Select Agent</mat-label>
            <mat-select (change)="agentSelect($event.target.value)" formControlName="agent_id" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let agent of listOfAgents" [value]="agent.id"  
                [disabled]="agent.disabled!=undefined || agent.disabled!=null">
                {{agent.company_name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
</div>
<div formArrayName="ManufacturerArray" *ngFor="let item of manArray.controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="boxClass">

        <mat-form-field>

            <mat-label>Select Manufacturer</mat-label>
            <mat-select (change)="manufacturerSelect($event.target.value)" formControlName="agent_id" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let manufacturer of listOfManufacturer" 
                [disabled]="manufacturer.disabled!=undefined || manufacturer.disabled!=null" 
                [value]="manufacturer.id">
                {{manufacturer.company_name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
</div>
```

In Html code, i added the `Change event` so that we get to know about the value alteration.

**.ts File**

```
agentSelect(value) {
   let agentArray =  this.form.get('AgentArray') as FormControl;
   let ManufacturerArray =  this.form.get('ManufacturerArray') as FormControl;
    this.agentArray.valueChanges.subscribe(checked => {
      if (checked) {
        this.agentArray.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.ManufacturerArray.setValidators(null);
      }
      this.ManufacturerArray.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.agentArray.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
  manufacturerSelect(value) {
    let agentArray =  this.form.get('AgentArray') as FormControl;
   let ManufacturerArray =  this.form.get('ManufacturerArray') as FormControl;
    this.ManufacturerArray.valueChanges.subscribe(checked => {
      if (checked) {
        this.ManufacturerArray.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.agentArray.setValidators(null);
      }
      this.ManufacturerArray.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.agentArray.updateValueAndValidity();
    });  
  }
```

You can also get the help from the below [link](https://netbasal.com/three-ways-to-dynamically-alter-your-form-validation-in-angular-e5fd15f1e946)

Comment: Thank you for your solution.. but its  not working for me.. Because i am asking for formcontrol inside of formArray not formControl ..

Comment: yes, It might be helpful any other scenario.. but not in this scenario.. On click of save only we can do this..

Comment: Then on what scenario you want @Rekha ?

Comment: I am asking for formArray inside i have 3 formcontrol.. one formcontrol only gets validators while manufactuter dont have.. but its not working for me..

Comment: Looking into it. @Rekha